# FindRoot not working for a system of two equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am using to find a solution for two dimensional system. Here is the code I use

```
paramFinal = 
  {σ -> 1.8, ψ -> 1.7, α -> 0.3, β -> 0.1, ρ -> 0.02, θ -> 0.05, δ ->0.05, 
   ϕ -> 0.8,ω -> 0.3, p -> 80};
```

After calibration

```
sol = 
  FindInstance[
    {ρ - ω + n - (c^-σ n^(ϕ (1-σ)))/ (s^-ψ) ==  0 /. 
       paramFinal /. s -> 1, c + n s ==  ψ s /. 
          paramFinal /. s -> 1}, 
     {n}, {c}, Reals] //Simplify
```

Whatever I have tried, I could not figure out the probem. It gives me the error

> FindInstance::intpm: Positive machine-sized integer expected at position 4 in FindInstance.

What am I missing on the code?

Comment: Well, the error message is telling you exactly what is the problem.  Have you checked the documentation to see what the 4th argument of FindInstance should be? You want `{n,c}` instead of `{n}, {c}`.  When you have an error, a good approach is to remove everything non-essential until the error goes away.  Then you know what caused it.  I notice that here you pasted the command as you used it without even trying to remove the Simplify from the end ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I looked at it but I did not really understand it. It does not change anything without Simplify or with. Sorry, I am a debutant on Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, there are real roots?

```
f = 
  {(ρ - ω + n - (c^-σ n^(ϕ (1 - σ)))/(s^-ψ) == 0) /. 
    paramFinal /. s -> 1, (c + n s - ψ s == 0) /. 
      paramFinal /. s -> 1};
FindInstance[f, {c, n}, Reals]
```

> FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.

```
ContourPlot[f, {c, 0, 5}, {n, 0, 2}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: @m-goldberg Thanks! How do you do that?